# Errors extending a Java Interface in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a basic Java interface defined as follows:

```java
public interface Action {
    void execute(Metadata var1, Parameter var2);
}
```

I'm trying to extend it in Clojure but keep getting errors. After importing the class into my namespace, I've tried using `reify` as follows:

```clj
(defn action [action-fn]
  (reify Action
    (execute [metadata parameter] (action-fn metadata parameter))))
```

but that throws a compiler illegal argument exception:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't define method not in interfaces: execute
```

Next I tried using `proxy`

```clj
(defn action [action-fn]
  (proxy [Action] []
    (execute [metadata parameter] (action-fn metadata parameter))))
```

That compiles successfully, and my editor (IntelliJ + Cursive) navigates to the interface definition via a border decoration, but trying to invoke execute on a generate proxy fails:

```clj
(.execute (action (fn [_ _] "Test action")))
```

throws the following:

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: execute for class
```

Finally I tried using deftype as follows:

```
(deftype cljAction [action-fn]
  Action
  (execute [metadata parameter] (action-fn metadata parameter)))
```

which throws the same compiler error as for `reify`, e.g:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't define method not in interfaces: execute
```

Trawling through various blog posts and SO answers seems to suggest it's a problem with the arity of arguments, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the `this` reference from the function. So what you want is this:

```
(defn action [action-fn]
  (reify Action
    (execute [this metadata parameter] (action-fn metadata parameter))))
```

Obviously because you are not using it you can just call it `_` or whatever makes the most sense in your opinion. When you are calling the function you want this:

```
(.execute (action action-fn) metadata parameter)
```

This differs slightly from when you are implementing a protocol. See https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/definterface for more information.

Comment: Ah, that did the trick, thanks! including the `this` reference eliminated the compiler error and the following code at the REPL works as expected:

`(.execute (action (fn [metadata parameter] (println "Test action"))) nil nil)`

Comment: @OliverMooney, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

ponzao's answer is correct. But note that Cursive can actually fill in the stubs for you: you can write `(reify Action)` and then (with the cursor in that form somewhere) choose *Code->Generate...* and choose to implement methods. Cursive will then fill in the stubs with the correct form. This currently only works when implementing interfaces, not protocols.

Comment: I didn't realise that, thanks! I've mainly used IntelliJ as a host for Cursive, most of the Java-oriented menu options are unknowns so far...